# How to transform raw data into node and edge lists?

Tags: nodes, edges, gephi

I am new to Gephi. I have conducted a questionnaire among healthcare workers (general practitioners, etc.) and we asked them which types of healthcare colleagues they would consult if they have questions on vaccines. So,there are several general practitioners in the samples, so, in order not to confuse Gephi I will need to number those participants, I think?

Moreover, what to do with the colleagues (e.g., general practitioners, medical specialists, etc.) they indicate to consult? We do not know who they are or whether they would recommend the other person back, or whether they participated in the survey as well.
How to create a node list and edge list based on his?
Who are the nodes; the participants only or also the colleagues they mention? Should I number all general practitioners, regardless of whether it is a participant or nominee?

Example of the data:

Participant GenPrac1 contacts other GenPrac and physician in public health

Participant Medical specialist1 contacts a GenPrac and a physician in public health

Participant GenPrac2 contacts a Medical spec

Many, many thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: It seems to me that you better model *People* (general practitioners, medical specialists, etc.) as *nodes* and their *connection*, (consulting, recommendation) as an *edges*. Better also number the nodes like eg. `GenPrac1, GenPrac2,...,GenPracN` and `MedSpec1, MedSpec2, ..., MedSpecM`. The point is that whether the Person participated or not in the survey, _it must become a node_. An edge can take the form `(MedSpec1, GenPrac3)`, if there is some kind of relationship between `MedSpec1` and `GenPrac3`. There are however, many variations of that pattern, depending on what you want to study.

Comment: Please also note that StackOverflow is not really a good place for those kinds of questions. I would recommend to register to [Gephi group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/gephi/)